# PHP change Field Value when displaying on front end

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms, field

The field name 'day' has 5 values which are:
'mon' 'tue' 'wed' 'thur' or 'fri'.

When I echo these out on the front end with:

```
                <div class="listing-footer-left">

                    <?php $day = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(),'day', true );

                    echo $day; ?>

                </div>
```

I would like to display the value 'mon' as 'Mondays' and the value 'tue' as 'tuesdays' etc

Please could you let me know how this is possible.

Many thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `date` and `strtotime` like this:

https://3v4l.org/RlHkr

```
<?php
$day = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(),'day', true );
echo date('l', strtotime($day));
echo $day;
?>
```

EDIT: This just works for singular though, I don't think theres a built-in locale-aware solution for plural - if you just need it to work for english you can just make an array:

https://3v4l.org/L8Jr4

```
<?php

$arr = ['mon' => 'Mondays', 'tue' => 'Tuesdays']; // ...
$day = 'mon';
echo $arr[$day];
```

or use the approach from above and just append a `s`:

https://3v4l.org/2gkvI

```
<?php
$day = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(),'day', true );
echo date('l\s', strtotime($day));
echo $day;
?>
```

---

References:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: Amazing thanks very much, the array option is exactly what I was looking for! Knew it would be quite simple. Thanks mate

Comment: @Matt-SalusaCommunity cool. You can accept the answer if it helped you.